# Manually setting QUARANTINE_THRESHOLD and DISCONNECT_THRESHOLD in testcafe does not work

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I changed the QUARANTINE_THRESHOLD and DISCONNECT_THRESHOLD in test_run_controller.ts file to 1 million each and built successfully however, my test still fails after around 1000-10000 restarts with the error :

ERROR The Chrome 89.0.4389.90 / Linux 0.0 browser disconnected. This problem may appear when a browser hangs or is closed, or due to network issues.

Is there something else that may be forcing testcafe to quit? or is the issue in browser perhaps?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to the error, your browser hangs for some reason. The problem could be in the way you organize your tests. It's likely that you have some code that leads to memory leaks, and after 1000-10000 restarts, your machine does not have enough RAM to run the browser.

Please clarify why you need to restart your tests 1000-10000 times.

> I changed the QUARANTINE_THRESHOLD and DISCONNECT_THRESHOLD in
> test_run_controller.ts file

We are working on the quarantine mode configuration, so you will have the capability to change quarantine options out of the box.